# How to make variable return number and not function?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am caught by this error and can't seem to resolve it. Why would the following code return a function and not a number?

```
let second = function(){ 
    return 100
};

console.log(second);
```

Comment: Because you need to call the function: `console.log( second() )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add `()` to end to actually execute the function.

```
console.log(second());
```

Otherwise you are just accessing the variable `second` which contains a reference to a `function`. In javascript you use parentheses to *call* a function.